# Ternary operator for Setstate

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Ternary operator for Setstate

Is it possible to do this? I want for example set a variable containing the correct state to setState to.

```
   this.setState({
        isFiltered: isFilteredCopy,
        languagesFilter: isFilteredCopy
    });
}
```

I want to choose either isFiltered or languagesFilter, based on whether the state Array the function which is sent into, is the corresponding one.

Is it possible to also do multiple conditional ternary?

Like I got 4 options to choose based on condition in general?

Answer (score 7):

One possible approach is using [computed property name](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames):

```
this.setState({
  [someCondition ? 'isFiltered' : 'languagesFilter']: isFilteredCopy
});
```

> Is it possible to also do multiple conditional ternary? Like I got 4 options to choose based on condition in general?

Syntax allows it, but it'll become confusing. A better option seems to be moving this choice into separate function:

```
function getFieldName(condition) { ... }
```

... then calling this function as part of computed property name:

```
this.setState({
  [getFieldName(condition)]: isFilteredCopy
});
```

As a matter of fact, the whole pattern looks a bit weird; perhaps it might be beneficial to redesign a model instead, depending on use case.

Comment: Separate function +1

Comment: I'm getting a computed property name must be of type 'string' 'number' 'symbol' or 'any' when I try... 

`const GetPropertyName = function (isFiltered) {

        let filter = 
       JSON.stringify(isFiltered)==JSON.stringify(this.state.isFiltered) && 
       'isFiltered' || 
       JSON.stringify(isFiltered)==JSON.stringify(this.state.languagesFilter) && 
       'languagesFilter';
    return filter;
}`

My code condition is to check whether an array is identical to the state and determine if its true or not.

Comment: Why did you use `&&` and not ternary?

Comment: The reason this error appears is exactly because of short-circuit nature of `&&` operator: if both comparisons fail, `false` is returned. As a sidenote, you're wasting JSON.stringify here by applying it for the same array twice; but we're going out of the scope of this question, I'm afraid.

Comment: @raina77ow Any suggestion how I can fix and avoid this?

Comment: Just use `if`: `const isFilteredStringified = JSON.stringify(isFiltered); if (isFilteredStringified === JSON.stringify(this.state.isFiltered) return 'isFiltered'; if (other check) return 'languagesFilter';` What should be done if both checks fail?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) with its updater like this:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return true ? {isFiltered: isFilteredCopy} : {languagesFilter: isFilteredCopy}
})
```

---

Ah, I overlooked the value to be different. You can use @raina77ow answer, a better way. Also, like this:

```
const filter = true && 'isFiltered' || 'languagesFilter'
this.setState({
  [filter]: isFilteredCopy
});
```

As per your updated question, you can use like this:

```
const filter = (condition1 && 'isFiltered') 
               || (condition2 && 'languagesFilter') 
               || (condition3 && 'otherFilter')
               || 'defaultFilter' // if no condition matches
```

But with this syntax, just assure which condition should be checked first.

Comment: So far, none of the options works...

The object state is an array of numbers.
and the problem is probably that [variable] is a string maybe?